# Does multicore CPU schedule multiple threads of same process at same time

Tags: c, linux

I am having big question from long back. basically i would want to know if have N number of processes running on LINUX system and each thread having multiple threads ( On multi core CPU).

In LINUX os is there a posibillity that linux runs multiple threads of same process on diffrent cores at same instance if time. I am having doubt because linux threads share common virtual space may be linux has to syncronize the threds it can be burden for OS is what i am thinking.

if linux does not schedule same process threds at same instance of time i think it could give better performance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I didn't downvote, but I think your question is being downvoted because this is the type of basic information you can find yourself using Google.  Please read the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: You're jumping to a lot of false conclusions based on imcomplete and/or incorrect information!  Yes: different threads can use different cores and/or different CPUs.  Yes, the fact that threads in the same process share the same address space means that you have to protect global variables.  That's true of *any* OS.  And no, virtual memory has little or nothing to do with thread- or CPU- scheduling (except, of course, for a process - in ANY OS - becoming blocked waiting for a page fault from disk).  And no, I didn't downvote you either.

Answer (score 4):

Of course it can. If it didn't then there'd be little point to the application being multithreaded in the first place other than to cover for the programmer's weaknesses.

Comment: Or the programming language's or libraries' weaknesses. Lots of times the reason you need threads is to deal with standard or third-party library code that can't be used in a non-blocking manner. DNS lookups come to mind. If you want to ensure hostname lookup semantics match the standard OS behavior, the only way to do them without blocking is to make a new thread to call `gethostbyname`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a system with N cores, you can take advantage of it by parallelizing (dividing) the application workload, let's say into m tasks or threads. By doing this, the system can simultaneous execute the m tasks among the n cores.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is of course supported and as you suspect it is quite a complicated burden. For (a lot) more detail please see this excellent (and very detailed) memory management overview:
http://lwn.net/Articles/250967/